# Matrices of self-adjoint operators

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, self-adjoint-operators

Fix a finite-dimensional real inner product space. Does a self-adjoint operator have a symmetric matrix with respect to all bases, or just with respect to orthonormal bases? Also, does this change at all when one admits a pseudo-Euclidean inner product, rather than the (standard) Euclidean inner product?